# Is it possible to classify songs by genres based on spectrograms?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, classification

Is it possible to categories songs based on their spectrograms using image recognition or would there need to  more features? I was thinking that the spectrograms might also run into problems with EDM songs. Such as House music being closely related to their sounds. Would there have to be immense amount of data? I was thinking of using a CNN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use spectrograms for genres classification. See relevant articles [Music genre recognition using spectrograms](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5977391/) or blog post [here](http://deepsound.io/music_genre_recognition.html). The later link did use CNN for this task.

If you need training data, [GTZAN](http://marsyasweb.appspot.com/download/data_sets/) or [FMA](https://github.com/mdeff/fma) could be your starting point.